# creating JS Pixel Manipulation effect

Tags: javascript

I am keen to try and recreate something on my website with effects similar to what can be seen here?

http://www.williamhoza.com/text/?t=Hello

I have searched the web for canvas pixel manipulation along with other searches and cannot see anything that could help with this.

It would be great if someone has any knowledge of how this effect is achieved or even has information as to where I should be looking for help

also, would it be possible to achieve effect with an image?

Comment: The source code is right there in the page you linked. What's the problem?

Comment: Look into [`P5.js Library`](https://p5js.org/) which is a Processing library. [`The Coding Train`](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCvjgXvBlbQiydffZU7m1_aw) does plenty of tutorials on how to use it.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca is right. All of the code is inside of the source of the page. Paste `view-source:http://www.williamhoza.com/text/?t=Hello` into your URL if you're in Chrome.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I am new to Javascript. rather than copy what is there, I would like a more informative explanation, incase I need to make any edits myself

Comment: @SupGen The idea of learning how some code works is by messing around with it. Copy the source code and start by randomly editing values one-by-one to understand how the structure works.

Comment: I'm afraid a more informative explanation of a 200-lines script is a bit too much for the stackoverflow format :(

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I appreciate that. there are also elements in that which I do not want to include in my own site such as being able to change the text that is shown. I would rather the text be set to what I chose. The answer below helped my understanding quite a bit actually and as you can see it was very simple

Comment: Well, good for you :) Good luck on your journey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the text into particles. Each particle should have a vector pointing to it's start position. If you move you mouse close, you should add a new vector to the particles around the mouse. This way you particles will move, but return to the original position.